# Run a load Test using C# and save all outputs

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, load-testing, web-testing

Hi I have some pre recorded webtests and I want to programatically design and run load tests and save all outputs including graphs. Also I would like to know if these tests can be run from my machine on agent machines so that the processes going on my machine donot hamper the tests. Any help on this is most welcome. I intend to use C#(Visual studio 2012) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web test plugins and load test plugins can modify many aspects of a test as it runs.

Have not found any way of programmatically saving all the result graphs etc. However, all the data for the graphs is saved in a SQL database and so it should be possible to write your own SQL queries etc to generate any report you want. For details of the database in Visual 2010 see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2010/02/12/description-of-tables-and-columns-in-vs-2010-load-test-database.aspx . For 2012 a few additional tables and fields were added but the document is still useful.

In answer to a comment. Simple web searches quickly find the pages you want, but here are some good ones.

How to: Create a Load Test Plug-In
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms243153.aspx

How to: Create a Web Performance Test Plug-In
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Installing a configuring test agents
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd648127.aspx

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments, can you please let me know where I can find sample code for Web test plugins and load test plugins and how to enable to option of running the tests on agent machines from my machine?

Comment: @GBh Some links added to the answer.

Comment: @GBh Has you problem been resolved? If not then what remains? If it has been resolved then please accept the answer or post your own solution as an answer. Otherwise the question remains open and we do not know whether you still need help.